# Java regular expression to match the words

Tags: java, regex, string, list

I have a following list of words:

```
List<String> words = Arrays.asList("Tom", "Emily", "Kate","Ava","Mark");
```

Looking for a java regular expression that returns the list of words which start with vowels `[a,e,i,o,u]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `^` character marks the beginning of the string, and you can use square brackets to have one of the several options:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[aeiou].*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
List<String> startingWithVowels =
    words.stream().filter(w -> p.matcher(w).matches()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find words starting with a vowel using [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream):

```
words = words.stream()
             .filter(word -> word.toUpperCase()
                                 .matches("[AEIOU].*"))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or use the [`Iterator<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) to remove the unwanted items from the list:

```
Iterator<String> iterator = words.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    if (!iterator.next().toUpperCase().matches("[AEIOU].*")) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Both of them upon `System.out.println(words);` will result in:

> [Emily, Ava]

---

Edit: The Regex matching with [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) ([`@Mureinik`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2422776/mureinik)) is a better approach. Yet applicable to the cases I introduced you above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one: /[AEIOUaeiou]\w+/